# Create vote/survey SMS without audience

Tags: marketing-cloud, list

We have created a multi-step SMS with vote/survey SMS using MobileConnect. When we created a vote/survey SMS, it´s required an audience.list. When we done it, we recieved the SMS at send.
But these SMS are steps of multi-step. The first SMS have the needed list
Is there any way to create vote/survey SMS´s without a list??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up the Vote/Survey, use the "External Source" selection instead of the sending options. This allows you to proceed without creating an audience.